# Rocco Theme Functions error implode

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes, implode

I get this error on my website:

Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/content/77/12366977/html/wp-content/themes/rocco/functions.php on line 86

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/content/77/12366977/html/wp-content/themes/rocco/functions.php on line 86

---

I think the line that the error is occuring is this one:
* Excerpt
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
function mfn_excerpt($post, $length = 55, $tags_to_keep = '', $extra = ' [...]') {

```
if(is_int($post)) {
    $post = get_post($post);
} elseif(!is_object($post)) {
    return false;
}

if(has_excerpt($post->ID)) {
    $the_excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
    return apply_filters('the_content', $the_excerpt);
} else {
    $the_excerpt = $post->post_content;
}

$the_excerpt = strip_shortcodes(strip_tags($the_excerpt, $tags_to_keep));
$the_excerpt = preg_split('/\b/', $the_excerpt, $length * 2+1);
$excerpt_waste = array_pop($the_excerpt);
$the_excerpt = implode($the_excerpt);
if( $excerpt_waste ) $the_excerpt .= $extra;

return apply_filters('the_content', $the_excerpt);
```

What should I do and where should I add the code, if adding code is the solution? 
Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all [PHP implode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) takes two arguments if the explode is not standard and proably this is the case. You are using only one

Also there is no "array_map" in your example. Is really the same code?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't see the array_map code.

Comment: * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
function mfn_get_comment_excerpt($comment_ID = 0, $num_words = 20) {
 $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
 $comment_text = strip_tags($comment->comment_content);
 $blah = explode(' ', $comment_text);
 if (count($blah) > $num_words) {
  $k = $num_words;
  $use_dotdotdot = 1;
 } else {
  $k = count($blah);
  $use_dotdotdot = 0;
 }
 $excerpt = '';
 for ($i=0; $i<$k; $i++) {
  $excerpt .= $blah[$i] . ' ';
 }
 $excerpt .= ($use_dotdotdot) ? '[...]' : '';
 return apply_filters('get_comment_excerpt', $excerpt);
}

Comment: My site is stephaniesander.com